# How can I calculate the percent change between the year 2000 and 2017 of NHL data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataset I have has 17 years of data which contains # of people watching games in the field for 31 teams. What I want to do is to find the percent change in audience of teams from 2000-2017. For example, Tampa Bay’s attendance at home was 611,173 in the 2000-01 season and grew to 782,772 in the 2017-18 season. Thus, the percentage growth in home attendance between these two seasons was 100*(782,772 - 611,173) / 611,173 = 28%. I don't know how to approach the task. I tried to groupby the team name but couldn't figure out a way to code the mathematical expression (#of audience from 2017-# of audience from 2000)/(# total games)*100 for all 31 teams. Can show me a way to approach the problem?

Comment: Correction : mathematical expression should be (#of audience from 2017-# of audience from 2000)/(#  of audience from 2000))*100 instead!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I'd like to introduce you to the submission guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please format your question so that you get easily get help from the community.